# How to keep a particular class member in proguard? Error Expecting separating ',' or closing ')' before arg

Tags: java, proguard

There is something wrong with the syntax below:

```
  -keepclassmembers class * {
 public void changeView(android.view.View v);
```

}

Error: Expecting separating ',' or closing ')' before 'v'

Not seeing that it really needs a , or ) but thats the error i'm getting.

Seeing the exact same error for:

```
-keep class com.test.activities.MyActivityActivity {
public void changeView(android.view.View v);
```

}

Would someone care to share what is wrong with this?

Its says in the manual under Processing Callback Methods:

```
 -keep class mypackage.MyCallbackClass {
void myCallbackMethod(java.lang.String);
}
```

Is that not exactly what I am doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no point in giving variable names (`v`) in your signature, since they are not there in the byte code anyway (except in debug information which is ignored/stripped by Proguard).

And the error is right, since without a variable name, there will come a `)` (or a `,` in case of not last parameter) before/instead the `v`.

Comment: -keepclassmembers class * { *** @color/dark_brown(...); }
What is the issue here I always get Error Thanks

Comment: @Mangesh please do not hijack questions with your comments, if you have your own question, please ask it individually.